# Google Analytics thinks that Paid Search is Organic Traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have been running Google Ads campaigns for last 2 weeks and just noticed that all Google Ads clicks are counted as Organic traffic inside Google Analytics (I know that, because there has been huge spike in Organic traffic when I started Google Ad Campaigns, other channels stayed the same) and Paid Search just sits at 0.

On Google Analytics, I can see numbers from my Google Ad campaigns when I go to Acquisition -> Google Ads -> Campaigns, they are there, but they are still not counted as paid search which messes up the reporting.

I have done research online, most common problem is account linking and auto-tagging, but Google Ads and Google Analytics accounts are properly linked and auto-tagging is on.

Earlier in the year all Google Ads activity was going into "Paid Search" with no problem and I haven't changed anything in Analytics and even it is the same Google Ad Campaign.

Comment: Even though the two accounts are linked, is that particular View selected to receive the Google Ads data? Also have you tested that gclid is working correctly eg no redirects, is not being changed to lower case etc?  
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2938246?hl=en